# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: RecyclerView does not support scrolling to an absolute position

Tags: android

Getting this error on Samsung GT-S7562 Android 4.0.4. I am not calling scrollTo method through code. It is getting called internally. Please help

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: RecyclerView does not support scrolling to an absolute position.
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.scrollTo(RecyclerView.java:941)
            at android.view.View.setScrollX(View.java:7010)
            at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.nCallIntMethod(Native Method)
            at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.access$200(PropertyValuesHolder.java:35)
            at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder$IntPropertyValuesHolder.setAnimatedValue(PropertyValuesHolder.java:815)
            at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.animateValue(ObjectAnimator.java:476)
            at android.animation.ValueAnimator.animationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:1145)
            at android.animation.ValueAnimator.setCurrentPlayTime(ValueAnimator.java:551)
            at android.animation.LayoutTransition.startChangingAnimations(LayoutTransition.java:813)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1805)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2632)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: "I'm having this error with code that I haven't provided, help!" isn't a question that we can answer. What exactly is the question here?

Comment: did you find any solution? i am also getting the same error..

Comment: Take a look on my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/28448691/1224247

Comment: Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58928008/9764941

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You will get this error on some Samsung, Sony,... Implementation of ICS. Both I've founded that include strange internal view managements. 
One solution to this is to extend **RecyclerView** (Or the class that generate the issue) with your own class and use that one. In that class you will basically "eat" all possible render exceptions for these devices. It's ugly, it's awful but it's all what I can do to fix this kind of issues.

For your specific issue with scrollTo....

```
package com.stackoverflow.customviews;

public class CustomRecyclerView extends RecyclerView{

  private static final String TAG = "CustomRecyclerView";

  public CustomRecyclerView(android.content.Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  public CustomRecyclerView(android.content.Context context, android.util.AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs);
  }

  public CustomRecyclerView(android.content.Context context, android.util.AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
      super(context, attrs, defStyle);
  }

  @Override
  public void scrollTo(int x, int y) {
      Log.e(TAG, "CustomRecyclerView does not support scrolling to an absolute position.");
     // Either don't call super here or call just for some phones, or try catch it. From default implementation we have removed the Runtime Exception trown 
  }
}
```

Then you can replace in your layout xml this new class:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<com.stackoverflow.customviews.CustomRecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks @cohnen  your solution helped me in solving the problem

Comment: you Genius.Thanks @cohnen

Comment: Just a heads up, I am experiencing this same exact problem on some samsung devices that are running 4.4.2 as well.

Comment: I have this crash on android5.0 nexus4 and emulator. Is there better solution?

Comment: Got this crash using animated layout changes (with linear layout). Not like I ever asked it to scroll in the first place :/

Comment: Do you have the steps necessary to reproduce this on the emulator @StasShakirov? That'd be real useful.

Answer (score 53):

I had same problem, for me it was because I had

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

for my recycler view's parent. I removed that and it worked.

Comment: have you find solution to keep this to true and avoid OP's problem?

Comment: Looks like it was fixed with `recyclerview-v7:23.2.1`.

Comment: @SqueezyMo I'm still having this issue with `recyclerview-v7:23.3.0`

Comment: still happening on com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0.

Comment: Worked for me, although slightly different.  I had it in the view in the adapter instead of the recyclerview parent. Perhaps it can be caused by any of the views within the hierarchy? Worth checking them all for 'android:animateLayoutChanges="true"', or if they have the programmatic version `setLayoutTransition(new LayoutTransition());` and remove them.

Comment: This should be accepter answer, because the issue exist only if you have android:animateLayoutChanges="true" to the recyclerview parent

Comment: I had the same issue, but I still wanted the animation it provides.  Putting the following in `onClick` in my adapter allowed me to have my cake and eat it too: `TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(binding.constraintLayout)`

Answer (score 14):

To make scroll programmatically you need to use LayoutManager. For example LinearLayoutManager has scrollToPositionWithOffset. GridLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager - so you also can use this. Code works for me:

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
if (layoutManager instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {
   LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) layoutManager;
   linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0, newTopMargin - defaultMargin);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked without the need to subclass.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same warning problem due to the following in the recycler parent:

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

If you want to keep the animation, just put the recycler inside another parent like a `framelayout`. It worked fine for me, and the animation also plays fine.

Answer (score 6):

As others said in their answers `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` in `RecyclerView`'s parent layout cause this problem, but the solution is easier than the others said.

Just you need to put your `RecyclerView` in a new `Layout` that doesn't have `android:animateLayoutChanges` property.

For Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

    ...

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

The warning appears only if RecyclerView is inside direct parent view with XML attribute

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

like @Aalap and @luis said (@luis even gives one idea how to leave this XML attr with almost same layout hierarchy).

I would like to post a little bit diff option. If you have this kind of situation probably you want to animate some view changes inside the parent layout but not inside the RecyclerView, otherwise this one will be a little bit wrong. If you need RecyclerView animations , better to do this inside the RecyclerView adapter not XML.

So at the end if you need animations when something change outside of the RecyclerView, better to put

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

not into the parent View of the RecyclerView, but into the parent view to the view that you want to animate.

Short example :

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/top_parent_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
<FrameLayout
  android:id="@+id/header_view"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:clickable="true"
  android:animateLayoutChanges="true">
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/header_arrow_icon"
    android:layout_width="24dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"/>
</FrameLayout>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
  android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

This means : Avoid wrapping RecyclerView with parent view which has android:animateLayoutChanges="true"