# Recycler View Crash onkeyboard closing

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I build a recyclerview like so:

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

currentResults = new ArrayList<Stuff>();
stuffAdapter = new StuffAdapter(currentResults, getActivity());
recyclerView.setAdapter(stuffAdapter);
```

then when the user searches for things and results are returned, they're added to the adapter in the normal way

```
currentResults.clear();
currentResults.addAll(searchResponse.results);
restaurantAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

this is all very standard. the results are obtained via a searchview widget in an appcompat toolbar and a retrofit callback.

the problem is that there is one particular point where the user can close the keyboard, and the UI adjusts to fit, and then the whole thing crashes with

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: RecyclerView does not support scrolling to an absolute position. at  
android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.scrollTo(RecyclerView.java:941) at 
android.view.View.setScrollX(View.java) at  
android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.nCallIntMethod(Native Method) at 
android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.access$200(PropertyValuesHolder.java)
at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder$IntPropertyValuesHolder.setAnimatedValue(PropertyValuesH
```

Nobody is calling scrollto. I don't get why it's throwing this. Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Reading from another SO Question :

> [java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: RecyclerView does not support scrolling to an absolute position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28428409/java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-recyclerview-does-not-support-scrolling)

The problem is with some specific devices only, because of there Implementation of ICS. As the suggested work around, you can make a `CustomRecyclerView` that extend `RecyclerView` and override `scrollTo` that catch the error and stop the application to crash.

```
@Override
public void scrollTo(int x, int y) {
    Log.e(TAG, "CustomRecyclerView does not support scrolling to an absolute position.");
    // Either don't call super here or call just for some phones, or try catch it. From default implementation we have removed the Runtime Exception trown 
}
```

Comment: I no longer have the code to verify but this was reproducible across many devices and had to do specifically with the keyboard closing. that question doesn't appear to be the same issue.