# RecyclerView: UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-recyclerview

I am running into a strange issue with `RecyclerView` on certain devices (seemingly Samsung only for right now). I am getting the following error message:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: RecyclerView does not support scrolling to an absolute position.
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.scrollTo(RecyclerView.java:869)
   at android.view.View.setScrollX(View.java:9945)
   at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.nCallIntMethod(PropertyValuesHolder.java)
   at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.access$200(PropertyValuesHolder.java:35)
   at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder$IntPropertyValuesHolder.setAnimatedValue(PropertyValuesHolder.java:825)
   at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.animateValue(ObjectAnimator.java:571)
   at android.animation.ValueAnimator.animationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:1175)
   at android.animation.ValueAnimator.doAnimationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:1216)
   at android.animation.ValueAnimator.setCurrentPlayTime(ValueAnimator.java:524)
   at android.animation.LayoutTransition.startChangingAnimations(LayoutTransition.java:1021)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2206)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6637)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:814)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:614)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:584)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:800)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

The code within `RecyclerView.scrollTo(x,y)` is:

```
@Override
public void scrollTo(int x, int y) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
            "RecyclerView does not support scrolling to an absolute position.");
}
```

Strange that that is the implementation, but that's fine. The thing is, I am *not* calling that method. I use the following (per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28432632/371018) answer):

```
LinearLayoutManager manager = (LinearLayoutManager) mActivityList.getLayoutManager();
manager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0, 20);
```

The only workaround I have found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28432632/371018) which suggests subclassing `RecyclerView` and simply overriding the `scrollTo` method which makes sense. But to me, that doesn't seem like an optimal solution as it could result in the scroll not actually happening on those devices. Does anyone else have any other solutions for this?

Comment: My guess is that samsung modified some logic such that it creates layout transitions automatically and that thing just assumes scrolling to an absolute position is supported.
Can you create a bug report on b.android.com and add more information (device version, OS version, full thread dump if possible etc). Thanks!

Comment: it looks like this will only happen with v7 support & animated layout changes

Answer (score 12):

It happened to me when i set android:animatelayoutchanges=true. removing that solved the issue. There is one more example when this happens. It says it happens to only few devices. It is explained in this this thread [java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: RecyclerView does not support scrolling to an absolute position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28428409/java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-recyclerview-does-not-support-scrolling)

It answers the questions appropriately.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. I was very confused by this. Removing animatelayoutchanges was what I needed

Answer (score 1):

`LinearLayoutManager` doesn't support absolute scrolling, it just passes it through to the `RecyclerView`, which also doesn't support it.  What it *does* support is scrolling to a specific position in the dataset (`scrollToPosition()`), by a certain amount horizontally or vertically (`scrollHorizontallyBy()`, `scrollVerticallyBy()`), or to a position plus an offset (`scrollToPositionWithOffset()`).

Comment: Yeah, which is why I myself am not using the absolute scrolling method (RecyclerView.scrollTo(x,y)). I am using LinearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(). The error above is being called even though I'm not manually calling that method.

Comment: Fair enough, I had missed that you were using that specific call.  Odd, I've not seen this before; perhaps a Samsung specific issue?

Comment: That's what I am afraid of. As such, I've extended it and am simply not calling through to the super, but that seems like a hacky workaround.