# RecyclerView log statement: W/RecyclerView: RecyclerView does not support scrolling to an absolute position. Use scrollToPosition instead

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, logcat

I am updating an old Android project, and now I am getting this log statement from RecyclerView repeatedly:

`W/RecyclerView: RecyclerView does not support scrolling to an absolute position. Use scrollToPosition instead`

It occurs when the recyclerview is populated and displayed for the first time or when the items in the recyclerview are refreshed.

Logcat:

```
11-05 14:02:23.290 20209-20209/com.mydomain W/RecyclerView: RecyclerView does not support scrolling to an absolute position. Use scrollToPosition instead
11-05 14:02:23.290 20209-20209/com.mydomain W/RecyclerView: RecyclerView does not support scrolling to an absolute position. Use scrollToPosition instead
11-05 14:02:23.607 20209-20209/com.mydomain W/RecyclerView: RecyclerView does not support scrolling to an absolute position. Use scrollToPosition instead
11-05 14:02:23.607 20209-20209/com.mydomain W/RecyclerView: RecyclerView does not support scrolling to an absolute position. Use scrollToPosition instead
11-05 14:02:23.629 20209-20209/com.mydomain W/RecyclerView: RecyclerView does not support scrolling to an absolute position. Use scrollToPosition instead
[...]
```

The line repeats about 40+ times

However, as far as I can tell, in my code I am not scrolling to an absolute position. (Unless perhaps it is a byproduct of something else)

I have not been able to find much information about this warning.

Can anyone provide insight?

Comment: Whats the layout hierarchy? Are you using some sort of library in connection to this recyclerview?

Comment: @MidasLefko Layout hierarchy is CoordinatorLayout -> LinearLayout -> FrameLayout -> RecyclerView.  I'm using `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView` with `android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager`.  Not really using any special libraries, just Picasso in the RecyclerView.Adapter to load images in each list item.

Comment: @tenprint any success on this? Because i am also facing this issue

Comment: @Rohan unfortunately no

Answer (score 4):

I'm seeing exactly the same thing and in my case it's caused by the XML attribute

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

on the RecyclerView's parent - or programmatically setting a [LayoutTransition](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/LayoutTransition) on the parent view, that does the same thing. See [this answer on a different SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43027492/9434434). (It looks like it used to be an exception rather than a log in older Android versions, we're lucky in that regard.)

Removing the attribute fixes it, obviously. If (like me) you want to keep it, try organizing your view in such a way that the direct parent of the RecyclerView does not have it, like [Sniper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4466472/sniper) suggests in the post I linked to. Copying his example here in case it gets deleted:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/top_parent_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
<FrameLayout
  android:id="@+id/header_view"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:clickable="true"
  android:animateLayoutChanges="true">
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/header_arrow_icon"
    android:layout_width="24dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"/>
</FrameLayout>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
  android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

If (like me) you need the LayoutTransition animation on the RecyclerView, putting a wrapper view between the RecyclerView and the view with the layout animations is enough to get rid of the warnings:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Basically make sure the android:animateLayoutChanges property is not on the RecyclerView's parent.

The actual layout change animation works fine even with the warnings, though. I don't know if the performance impact of adding a layer to your view hierarchy is worth it. A better solution might be to subclass the RecyclerView and override the scrollTo (x, y) method to not print the log, like [another answer on the same SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28432632/9434434).

Answer (score 1):

Put this line in Adapter constructor, maybe it'll work for you:

```
this.setHasStableIds(true);
```